# vectorを用いた構造体配列の最大値の求め方

Tags: c++, c++11

```
typedef struct student_score{
    char* name;
    int m_n2;
}SudentScore;

int main()
{
    std::vector< SudentScore > vec;
    SudentScore _student = { 0 };

    _student.name = "hoge";
    _student.m_n2 = 2;
    vec.push_back(_student);

    _student.name = "aho";
    _student.m_n2 = 3;
    vec.push_back(_student);

}
```

max_elementを使うまでわかりましたが、構造体のm_n2のメンバに対して使うにはどうしたらよいのかわかりません

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[std::max_element](https://cpprefjp.github.io/reference/algorithm/max_element.html)の３引数バージョンを使用して

```
auto max = std::max_element(
    std::begin(vec),
    std::end(vec),
    [](const auto& l, const auto& r) { return l.m_n2 < r.m_n2; }
);
std::cout << "max student: " << max->name << ", score: " << max->m_n2 << std::endl;
```

とかでしょうか？

---

C++11タグが付けられていたので、`vec`初期化部分は

```
std::vector<student_score> vec{
    { "hoge", 2 },
    { "aho",  3 },
};
```

と書けます。また必要なければ`typedef`は使わず通常の構造体名を使用されることをお勧めします。